# Logstash -Could not find any executable java binary

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, environment-variables, logstash

I have ELK installed on a VM in my laptop.Elasticsearch is up and running.

`./bin/logstash -f logstash-filter.conf gives me the below error
Could not find any executable java binary. Please install java in your PATH or set JAVA_HOME.`

I tried setting up `JAVA_HOME` and  `$ PATH`, still the issue is persistent. Am I missing something?

```
 which java
/usr/bin/java


java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_45

echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/divija/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin
```

logstash-filter.conf

```
input { stdin { } }

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost 
    index=>"myindex"
}
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }`enter code here`
}
```

Answer (score 20):

I had to

> export JAVACMD=`which java`

to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

I know, it's an old thread, but I was also having the same problem and was doing a very silly thing.

I had updated my `$JAVA_HOME` var in `/etc/environment` but was not reloading the file because of which it was not taking effect, and running `source /etc/environment` solved my problem.

Comment: I don't get it, I am also facing the same issue. I tried setting `javacmd` and running `./system-install` from the `/usr/share/logstash/bin`. Im still facing the JAVA error. `could not find java; set JAVA_HOME or ensure java is in PATH` @raghav,@Raghav Garg

Comment: @SPishere, can you please share your output for `which java`, `java -version`, `echo $JAVACMD`, `echo $JAVA_HOME`,  `echo $PATH`.

Comment: They all are pointing to the right path, However i was able to fix it by adding JAVA_HOME=path/to/jdk in the startup.options.

Comment: @SPishere, so now your logstash is working, right? After setting `JAVA_HOME`.